# How to extend a file definition from an existing module in the node?

Tags: puppet

I use an older version of the example42 mysql module, which defines the mysql.conf file but not its content. Mmy goal is to just include the mysql module and add a content definition in the node.

```
class mysql {
    ...
    file { "mysql.conf":
        path => "${mysql::params::configfile}",
        mode => "${mysql::params::configfile_mode}",
        owner => "${mysql::params::configfile_owner}",
        group => "${mysql::params::configfile_group}",
        ensure => present,
        require => Package["mysql"],
        notify => Service["mysql"],
    }
    ...
}


node xyz
{
    include mysql
    File["mysql.conf"] { content => template("mymodule/mysql.conf.erb")}
}
```

The above code produces a "Only subclasses can override parameters"

What is the correct way to just add a content definition to an existing file definition?

Comment: Why not use a parameter passed to the mysql class to provide the path to the template?

Comment: because it is a predefined class, which i don't want to patch all the time i get a newer version of it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a *Resource collector*, described [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_resources.html#amending-attributes-with-a-collector). Resource collectors can override resource parameters even if not in a subclass. They are also more versatile, resources can be collected using tags or other parameters, not just the title.

```
node xyz
{
    include mysql
    File <| title == "mysql.conf" |> { 
        content => template("mymodule/mysql.conf.erb"),
    }
}
```

**Edit: using a subclass**

Another option is to declare a subclass and include it in the node definition:

```
class mysql_custom inherits mysql {
    File["mysql.conf"] { content => template("mymodule/mysql.conf.erb")}
}

node xyz {
    include mysql_custom
}
```

Comment: any other way without a resource collector?

Comment: It is possible to use a subclass. Answer edited. Have you had problems with resource collectors?

Comment: yes, i solved it by using subclasses, found the solution in: http://www.packtpub.com/puppet-2-7-for-reliable-secure-systems-cloud-computing-cookbook/book @ resource collectors: currently i don't get it up and running easily with debian squeeze and postgresql. some ruby probs.